# First difference for a function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

The first difference for a function $f$ can be given by the formula: 
$\Delta(n)=f(n+1)-f(n)$

> Complete the following:
>
> 1) The average rate of change of a function $f$ between $a$ and $b$ is
>   given by the formula:
>
> 2) The instantaneous rate of change of a function $f$ at a point $x_0$
>   is given by the formula:

I'm confused as to how to find the rate of change. 
I know the first difference of the function is given, but I'm confused as to how to use the given formula to find the rate of change from $a$ to $b$.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how to find the slope of $f$? The question is asking you to find the slope on the interval $(a, b)$ and then asking you to find the derivative at $f(x_0)$

Comment: No i dont know how to find the slope of f

Answer (score 1):

(1) gsdjpj bepgtm arv
vdrgf vdf vxcvnsgxdynthygfhxnyxty